# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.51:test-compile

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, m2eclipse

I cloned the [spring-boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui) Git repository into Eclipse and I get the following error. I have not made any code changes.

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: 
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.51:test-compile (execution: 
test-compile, phase: test-compile)
```

When I attempt to "auto-fix" the error I see this:

```
No marketplace entries found to handle kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.51:test-
compile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
```

[image]

**Here's my POM:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>compile</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
          <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
          <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
        </sourceDirs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>test-compile</id>
      <phase>test-compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test-compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sourceDirs>
          <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
          <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
        </sourceDirs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Error In Eclipse**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Quick Fix -> Mark goal compile as ignore in pom.xml
```

Choose both phases: `compile` & `test-compile` if coming from Markers list. In popup window quick fix shows only two rows with title `pom.xml` with line numbers respectively, check both.

It will create you block starting:

```
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
         <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only.
             It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
      ...
```

And just to stress read the comment in block: it does not affect the maven build

In case quick fix fails below is the whole plugin management section I managed to generate.

```
<pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
      <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
         <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
               <pluginExecutions>
                  <pluginExecution>
                     <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[1.1.60,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>compile</goal>
                           <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                     </pluginExecutionFilter>
                     <action>
                        <ignore></ignore>
                     </action>
                  </pluginExecution>
               </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: This what I did but it didnt seem like a "good" solution to ignore the problem. But this everything seems to work fine with this solution.

Comment: @javaPlease42 Yes it does not seem to at first glance. But if plugin has nothing to do with Eclipse build you can ignore it like this. Maven still does the required thing.

Comment: Yep my workspace is clean now. I will accept answer after some time unless a "better" solution does not show up. Thanks!